# Converting list of lists to a dictionary with multiple values for a key

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I need to write a function that accepts a list of lists representing friends for each person and need to convert it into a dictionary. 
so an input of `[['A','B'],['A','C'],['A','D'],['B','A'],['C','B'],['C','D'],['D','B'],['E']]` should return `{A:[B,C,D],B:[A],C:[B,D],D:[B],E:None}`

Input:

```
[['A','B'],['A','C'],['A','D'],['B','A'],['C','B'],['C','D'],['D','B'],['E']]
```

Expected Output:

```
{A:[B,C,D],B:[A],C:[B,D],D:[B],E:None}
```

Currently I am trying the following:

```
s=[['A','B'],['A','C'],['A','D'],['B','A'],['C','B'],['C','D'],['D','B'],['E']]

output=dict.fromkeys((set([x[0] for x in s])),[ ])

for x in s:
    if len(x)>1:
        output[x[0]].append(x[1])
    else:
        output[x[0]].append(None)
```

But the output is giving me all values for every key rather than returning only the corresponding values

The output i am getting is:

```
{
'A': ['B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'B', None],

 'B': ['B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'B', None],

 'C': ['B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'B', None],

 'D': ['B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'B', None],

 'E': ['B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'B', None]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the key-value pairs in the list of lists, but unpack the value as a list to accommodate the possible lack of a value:

```
s = [['A','B'],['A','C'],['A','D'],['B','A'],['C','B'],['C','D'],['D','B'],['E']]
output = {}
for k, *v in s:
    if v:
        output.setdefault(k, []).extend(v)
    else:
        output[k] = None
```

`output` becomes:

```
{'A': ['B', 'C', 'D'], 'B': ['A'], 'C': ['B', 'D'], 'D': ['B'], 'E': None}
```

Or if you don't mind that keys without a value get an empty list instead of `None`, you can simply do:

```
output = {}
for k, *v in s:
    output.setdefault(k, []).extend(v)
```

`output` would then become:

```
{'A': ['B', 'C', 'D'], 'B': ['A'], 'C': ['B', 'D'], 'D': ['B'], 'E': []}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a common dict comprehension to initiate the `dict`:

```
output = {x[0]: [] for x in s}
```

`dict.fromkeys` gives all keys the identical referential value. With a mutable value that is a problem. The comprehension will give each key an independent `list` object, in addition to being more readable.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the list you feed to `dict.keys` is only one reference across keys.

Your desired result is inconsistent. I recommend you choose an empty list for `'E'`, however much it *seems* `None` is more appropriate. With this adjusted requirement, you can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

```
from collections import defaultdict

L = [['A','B'],['E','C'],['A','D'],['B','A'],['C','B'],['C','D'],['D','B'],['E']]

dd = defaultdict(list)

for lst in L:
    if len(lst) > 1:
        dd[lst[0]].append(lst[1])
    else:
        dd[lst[0]]

print(dd)

defaultdict(list,
            {'A': ['B', 'C', 'D'],
             'B': ['A'],
             'C': ['B', 'D'],
             'D': ['B'],
             'E': []})
```

Answer (score 0):

### One of the way to solve this is as given below:

```
friend_combi = [['A','B'],['A','C'],['A','D'],['B','A'],['C','B'],['C','D'],['D','B'],['E']]  # Input to be processed

final_dict = {} #Empty dict to store result
for i in friend_combi: # loop through each element in list
    if final_dict.get(i[0]):  #if data present in dict then append else add
        final_dict[i[0]].append(i[1])
    else:
        final_dict[i[0]] = [i[1]] if i[1:] else None #check if value exist in list else save None
print (final_dict)
#Output --> {'A': ['B', 'C', 'D'], 'B': ['A'], 'C': ['B', 'D'], 'D': ['B'], 'E': None}
```

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function named `get_dictionary()` as the below code shows.

```
>>> def get_dictionary(l):
...     d = {}
...     for arr in l:
...         if len(arr) == 2:
...             key = arr[0]
...             if key in d:
...                 d[key].append(arr[1])
...             else:
...                 d[key] = [arr[1]]
...         else:
...             d[key] = None
...     return d
...
>>> l = [['A','B'], ['A','C'], ['A','D'], ['B','A'], ['C','B'], ['C','D'], ['D','B'], ['E']]
>>>
>>> get_dictionary(l)
{'A': ['B', 'C', 'D'], 'B': ['A'], 'C': ['B', 'D'], 'D': None}
>>>
```

> Pretty printing the dictionary as JSON.

```
>>> import json
>>>
>>> d = get_dictionary(l)
>>>
>>> print(json.dumps(d, indent=4))
{
    "A": [
        "B",
        "C",
        "D"
    ],
    "B": [
        "A"
    ],
    "C": [
        "B",
        "D"
    ],
    "D": null
}
>>>
```